# How to make GNU as output dependencies only?

Tags: assembly, makefile, gnu-assembler, 68000

I'm working on an assembly-language project using GNU bintools 2.25 built to target `m68k-elf`, with GNU `make` 3.81 handling the build. (As this is an assembly-only project, I do not have `gcc` built for `m68k`.)

In refining my build system, I'd like to be able to auto-generate a list of dependencies for each of my assembly files, similar to the `-M*` family of options to `gcc`.

I found that my copy of `m68k-elf-as` supports an `-MD` option for listing dependencies, so I added the following rule to my `Makefile`:

```
%.d: %.asm
    $(AS) --register-prefix-optional -m68000 -MD $@ $(ASFLAGS) $<
```

While this mostly works, there are two specific issues I have with it.

1. The `-MD` option requires a filename for writing the dependencies; I'd like to have this go to STDOUT so I can massage it with `sed` before `make` takes a look at it. I've tried giving it a single dash (`-`), but it creates a file with that name instead of directing to STDOUT.
2. Even with the `-MD` option enabled, `as` attempts to assemble the source code, which could generate an error and halt the entire build process. I would expect it to output the dependencies instead of assembling the code, rather than performing both actions.

While these are little more than annoyances right now, I can see this significantly affecting my builds as the project grows larger—particularly the latter. Is there a way to get `as` to output dependencies without trying to assemble the code?

Comment: I have no answers for you, other than hacking the code.  But I will point out that "generate the dependencies without assembling the code" is reflective of an outdated model of managing prerequisites.  The model described in the GNU make manual is sub-optimal in many ways.  Check out http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/ for a better model.  This won't solve your "output to stdout" issue, but it will solve your "output deps only without assembling".  The former could be solved with `sed -i` perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the -MD option says "'as' can generate a dependency file *for the file it creates*" (emphasis added), which says to me that it will not determine dependencies without assembling.  I'm not so fluent in assembler, but this is the GNU toolchain's standard model, serving also languages such as C in which it is impossible to determine the source dependencies without performing at least a full pre-processing run on the source.

In practice, that mode works fine if you use it as intended, updating dependencies only as a function of building the project.  You don't need to update dependencies outside that context, because if you update your source so as to add a new dependency, then that creates a need to rebuild that source anyway, its age relative to the new dependency notwithstanding.  Supposing that the Makefile is updated with the revised dependency information as a result of the next build, future builds will react appropriately to changes to the new dependency.

As for massaging the dependency output, having it written to a file only means you can't pipe it into `sed`, not that you cannot process it with `sed`.